# How to fix the loop if put an error value and return to ELSE statement on my given code in Java

Tags: java, loops

I want the output of the program to return to the question if the user inputs a wrong value.

This is for my homework. I've tried to search on Youtube and Google, but I can't identify my error and didn't show what is my error.

```
final int MINS_IN_AN_HOUR = 60;
final int AN_HOUR = 100;
final int LAST_MINUTE_OF_A_DAY = 2359;
int arrivalTime = 0;
int arrivalMins = 0;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Please enter the vehicle's arrival time (24-hour format): ");
while(true){
   arrivalTime = input.nextInt();
   if(arrivalTime >= AN_HOUR && arrivalTime <= LAST_MINUTE_OF_A_DAY){
      int hours = arrivalTime / AN_HOUR;  
      int minutes = arrivalTime - hours * AN_HOUR;   
      arrivalMins = hours * MINS_IN_AN_HOUR + minutes;  
      break;  // If user was correct, exit program
   }
   else{
      System.out.println("Please enter a valid number or enter a valid time");
      System.out.print("Please enter the vehicle's arrival time (24-hour format): ");
   }
}
```

The expected output must be the else statement and repeat the loop.

Comment: Looks ok at first glance. What exactly happens?

Comment: I typed string "error" then it must be a loop to else statement
Here's the output:
Please enter the vehicle's arrival time (24-hour format): error
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
 at Calculate_Parking_Fee.Parking_Fee.main(Parking_Fee.java:88)

Comment: when I execute your code I got this output:
Please enter the vehicle's arrival time (24-hour format): Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
 at HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:15)

Comment: This is expected behavior if the `Scanner` is asked for an `int` but doesn't get one. You should place a `try .. catch` around the `nextInt()` and `continue` in the `catch`.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'd really appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your code is not your condition, the problem is that you are reading the user input using `nextInt()`, without catching the exception in case the user input is not an int.

Simply replace this line:

```
arrivalTime = input.nextInt();
```

with a try...catch block

```
try {
    arrivalTime = input.nextInt();
} catch(InputMismatchException e) {
    arrivalTime = -1; // will trigger your else status
}
```